# Rhythmbox not shown in gconf-editor (Ubuntu 12.04)?

Tags: rhythmbox, gconf

In Rhythmbox, i'm trying to find out which folders are in the library watch list. According to the help file, you can use gconf-editor to add/remove them at /app/rhythmbox/library_locations. But, in the config editor, Rhythmbox is not listed. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has been probably moved to dconf-editor (note that this app begins with "d").

I do not see key "library_locations" in there - check youself in: org.gnome.rhythmbox